# how to set the column visibility as false while using the columns content in a data table in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, sapui5

when I set the column visibility as false with setVisible(false) on a datatable then the logic that I used to color the row by using that particular columns content is not working. It colors the rows correctly when I remove the column visibility as false. As you see, I am using the closest("tr") to get the closest row and color it based on the column cells value but I don't want this column to be shown in the table.

```
            oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({
                text : "Totaltype"
            }),
            template : new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value",
            "Totaltype", function(cellValue){ 
                //var backgroundColorChanged = false;
                switch(cellValue){  
                case 'S':  
                          backgroundColor = 'yellow';
                          backgroundColorChanged = true;
                          break;
                case 'T':  
                    backgroundColor = 'red';
                    backgroundColorChanged = true;
                    break;                              
                default:  
                          backgroundColor = 'white'; 
                }
                //if (backgroundColorChanged == true){
//                  backgroundColorChanged = false;
                cellId = this.getId(); 
                //$("#"+cellId).parent().parent().css("background-color",backgroundColor); 
                //}
                $("#"+cellId).closest("tr").css("background-color",backgroundColor);
                  return cellValue; 
            }),
            sortProperty : "Totaltype"
        }).setVisible(false));
```